# Dojo declare - the scope of default properties (instance or static)

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, declare, dojo-1.9

I've spent a lot of time debugging strage error in my component. That component have disabled/enabled buttons, but I haven't seen the effect. After a while, I've noticed, the buttons are changed in the last component instance I've created. The declaration looks so:

```javascript
  constructor: function(options) {
    for(var i in options){
      this[i] = options[i];
    }
  },
  domNode: null,
  grid: null,
  data: [],
  buttons: {},
```

In the debug, I've seen, that when I create second instance of my object:

```javascript
new CustomComponent({domNode: dojo.byId('secondid')})
```

the buttons are already set - their instance is shared by all instances!

In end effect, I've created a static variable in my component. This is not what I wanted! What is wrong in that declaration? How should I made 'buttons' instance separate for each component instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `CustomComponent` is a widget? Then you're doing some stuff wrong. The thing you do in your `constructor` (I suppose that's to populate your widget properties?) is not even necessary since that's already there by default when you use `dijit/_WidgetBase`.

Same with your property `domNode`, it's also there already by default if you use `dijit/_WidgetBase`.

My guess is that by overriding the constructor to act like this, you're actually doing some steps that the WidgetBase should do and thus messing up the private scope of the properties.

An example widget:

```
var CustomComponent = declare("my/CustomComponent", [WidgetBase], {
    grid: null,
    data: [],
    buttons: {}
});
```

This code does exactly the same as your widget and is a lot shorter.

An example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/jN3uY/) that has instance scoped properties (as you can see in the console log).

Comment: Well technically my component is a widget, but it doesn't inherit from anything. And I don't think it's the problem, it seems that everything in declare is a prototype, that is copied to child instances, so by buttons: {} you create a new Object, which will be copied to all instances. So the right way is to create that object in constructor.

Comment: Why don't you inherit from WidgetBase? It makes things a lot easier and I don't see any disadvantage.

Comment: I don't need anything from WidgetBase, at least I don't know about any such thing at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

I've inspected the problem more exact. The problem is, that the declare block is executed only once, therefore creating object **prototype**, which values are **copied** to instances.

So when I do `buttons: {}`, I create Object, which is then **copied** to all children. In end effect, all children have **the same** `buttons` instance - I've created a quasi-static field.

All bugs where gone when I've created the object in the constructor:

```javascript
  constructor: function(options) {
    for(var i in options){
      this[i] = options[i];
    }
    this.buttons = {}
    this.data = []
  },
```

Now every instance of my component have own `buttons` object.

In fact, my problem was exactly described [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/declare.html#arrays-and-objects-as-member-variables):

```javascript
dojo.declare("my.classes.bar", my.classes.foo, {
  someData: [1, 2, 3, 4], // doesn't do what I want: ends up being
```

Comment: It looks like you figured out the answer on your own, but [here's the documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/declare.html#arrays-and-objects-as-member-variables) on why that's necessary.

Comment: @ThomasUpton thank you for the link, I've used it to update my answer. Well, this is a problem with Dojo that you should read also outdated documentation :)

Comment: I just used the first result for dojo.declare because it seemed like you were using the 1.6-style global `dojo` object. [The current documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/declare.html#arrays-and-objects-as-member-variables) mentions the same thing.